# Filter Posts on Custom Fields and Show them on a new Page

Tags: custom-field

I want to filter my posts on a custom field and show them on a new site with a different URL. I know how to retrieve the posts but I don't know how to create this new "page". When I just created a PHP file in the folder, the templating engine does not seem to recognize it. What should I do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you put the good header in the template file as explained in this page ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Comment: I don't want to create a template. Maybe it's a little bit misleading but I don't want to do anything with the "new page dialog". I want a new, hard-coded URL to display special posts.